# Is it posible to take Screenshot of homepage using Android SDK.?

Tags: android, screenshot

I am currently working on an application in-which I need to take the screenshot of the homepage and also is it possible to get the exact location and count of the user's homepage widgets. i.e how many widgets are placed on user home page and whats there location or position on screen. X axis and Y axis coordinates etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For taking screenshots; Yes, it's possible, using the SDK, and the DDMS utility. Example here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3h1EYExu7c

For widgets on home-screen, not AFAIK. A problem that immediately arises is; what if the user have switched to other 3d-party HOME-screen with different widget-model? (For example, not grid-aligned, rendered on 3d surfaces or whatnot)

Comment: thanks Rawler. The first thing works. But about widget position I think I didn't explained well actually I'd like to get the user-home page widget locations and widgets count programatically.So is it possible?

Comment: If you by "user-home page" mean this: http://ticketbud.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/tbapsnp_04.png, then as far as I know, it cannot be done. The reason for why, as I outlined is that there are many possible launchers (I.E. see https://www.google.com/search?q=android+launcher&tbm=isch), and they don't by necessity follow the same model. For example, some may place widgets not on a grid, but on sides of a cube, on a circle, or other representations.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid you going to youtube, I'm posting the content here:

> Want to take a screenshot, but don't want to root your phone? Here is
>   how:
>
> 1) Install the Android SDK
>
> 2) Enable USB debugging on your device
>
> 3) Run DDMS from the tools directory
>
> 4) Select your phone from the list
>
> 5) Go in the menu, select Device, and then Screen capture. Whalah.